# The background for my website is not showing

Tags: html, css

[My Code](https://codepen.io/Crudge/pen/MWgBwZW)

```
body {background: url('images\Copy_of_mona-eendra-208388-unsplash.jpg') width 100% height 100% margin:0;}
```

I've got a codepen with the whole code on it, linked above. I am using the ATOM browser so I have just been pulling the object's path and pasting it in the url.

This is my first website so don't be too harsh on me, however, I welcome any critique.

For some reason I can't set a background image on the body no matter what I try.

Thanks,

Comment: @Enthus3d https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/8620333

Answer (score 0):

you missed `;` before `width` property, below id updated code.

```
body {background: url('images\Copy_of_mona-eendra-208388-unsplash.jpg'); width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0;}
```

Comment: thanks, but the image still doesn't show. i've checked the short hand and regular expression for setting the background and neither work.

Comment: just realized, column and semi column are missing every where, I have updated the code

Comment: I've copied in your edited code but for some reason it still wont show.